# Is powerfulest a valid superlative?

Tags: adjectives, superlative-degree

Whenever I type powerfulest in a word document or on here it’s always flagged as a grammar error.

I immediately consulted google and found some entries in low end “dictionaries”, but came across this reddit post:

["Powerfulest" isn't a word, and words are not real words until Merriam-Webster or OED recognizes them.](https://www.reddit.com/r/badlinguistics/comments/2vhdxl/powerfulest_isnt_a_word_and_words_are_not_real/)

So, in your opinion what’s the verdict on this one?

Comment: According to Merriam-Webster, "Merriam-Webster" is not a word. So I have no idea what that link is trying to say. Can someone please translate it into English for me? Meanwhile to answer your question, you cannot think of a word that is not a word. As soon as you think of a word, it is a word. So the question can never be, is this a word. The question always is, can I use it in this particular context to this particular effect. Please supply the context you are looking at, and the desired effect you are after. Otherwise we can't even tell if you can use the word "car" or "go".

Comment: No, it is "most powerful". Also, we don't accept opinion-based answers here - see the [tour] and [help].

Answer (score 1):

Powerfulest is definitely a less common form of superlative compared to the more commonly used “most powerful” ,but, as shown in [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22powerfulest%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2002,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en) the term is used.

From: [The Portable Walt Whitman](https://books.google.it/books?id=IeA4jU_Hs2wC&pg=PT449&dq=%22powerfulest%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQr6DxktXqAhUKmYsKHUZhAHs4ChDoATABegQIARAK#v=onepage&q=%22powerfulest%22&f=false)
By Walt Whitman

> Over those politicians and great and little rings, and over all their insolence and wiles, and over the powerfulest parties, looms a power, too sluggish maybe,

From [Stalker's Creek](https://books.google.it/books?id=DuJ8A-8V-ksC&q=%22powerfulest%22&dq=%22powerfulest%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiG9s7-k9XqAhWRw4sKHacNBgw4FBDoATACegQIARAS) by Will Cade

> He ' s the powerfulest man in town , and the closest thing to a rich one . By now I reckon he really is rich . Hey , want me to ask him ...